# Visa refused with a reason of being a threat to public health

Tags: visa-refusals, germany, schengen-visas

My parents who are living in India have applied for the Schengen tourist visa (Family / Friends) at the Consulate of Germany based in Mumbai.

After 2 weeks, we received an e-mail from the consulate to submit the pending document i.e. “Updated Vaccination Certificate with scannable QR-Code (Please self-check the QR-Code before sending the certificate).”

I self-checked the document by scanning the QR code which was not easy for me because initially the QR code was not recognized then I tried again to scan it for 30-60 sec which finally was successful, and I could verify the vaccine certificate.

Five days after the submission of the vaccine certificate, my mother’s visa was approved while my father’s visa was surprisingly refused stating the following reason "one or more Member States consider you to be a threat to public health as defined in point 21 of Article 2 of Regulation (EU) No 2016/399 (Schengen Borders Code)."

According to point 21 of Article 2 of Regulation (EU) No 2016/399 ‘threat to public health’ means any disease with epidemic potential as defined by the International Health Regulations of the World Health Organization and other infectious diseases or contagious parasitic diseases if they are the subject of protection provisions applying to nationals of the Member States. https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20190611&from=EN

The online explanation of the above statement is mentioned below: https://accra.diplo.de/blob/1120620/580d186ac10c2ade9c0f2aa333861abc/04-11-2020-schengen-visa-refusal-data.pdf

Please note that both - my mother and father- are fully vaccinated with COVISHIELD which is acceptable by the German Paul Ehrlich Institute.    Therefore, I am puzzled that why my father’s visa was rejected. But my Mother's visa was accepted.

My question is – Can the Schengen visa be rejected if the QR code of the Vaccine Certificate reflects trouble in scanning?
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Does the refusal only mention public health and not public policy and security? What makes you think it results from difficulties in scanning? And what do you want to do now? Find a way for your parents to go to Germany? I am not very familiar with this specific question but I suspect the courts leave governments quite a bit of discretion with health and safety exceptions.

Comment: That means that asking whether it can happen (it seem it just did) or even whether it was legal isn't really important on a practical level. Even if it were somehow unambiguously illegal, the real question is what kind of redress is available to you. And I don't think you and your father have many, apart from applying again in the future.

Comment: What was the problem with the QR code? Was it a scanned document?

Comment: The linked explanation about a "threat to public health" gives 3 possible reasons: a) You have submitted fake or false documents and / or made contradictory statements. b) You have attempted deceit. c) You have a negative entry in the AZR (Central Register of Foreigners); as long as this remains, it is usually not possible to grant you a visa.

Comment: Assuming there isn't more to the events as OP presented, I think it's likely that the QR code scanning issue happened to the consulate staffs also and mistakenly believed the certificate was invalid. If this is the case, more information on why QR code for your father has difficulties when scanning is required.

Comment: @WeatherVane The explanation is about the whole “public policy, public security, or public health“ triad that is used consistently across EU law and does not seem to elaborate on the “public health“ part. On the other hand, the question specifically mentioned “public health”, which is a bit surprising to me. Unless they have to do more (e.g. family of an EU citizen), I am used to consulates just slapping some boilerplate covering all these or checking a box on a form. And without further justification, you cannot do much about it. That's why I asked about this in my first comment.

Comment: Is the name on the certificate identically spelt to the name in his passport? Or is there room for interpretation that it’s not his certificate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because vaccine certificates are now a thing of the past in the Schengen area